# Calling a function to append text to a div does nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a form whereby a user clicks a button to append a set of form options to a div, in theory. The problem is, when I click the button, absolutely nothing (at least from what I can see) happens.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    ...

    <div class="tab-pane" id="rules">
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="addRule()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add New Rule</button><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Javascript is as follows:

```
<script>
    function addRule(){
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("rules");
        var content = document.createTextNode('<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control mb15" name="arule[]">
                    <option value="firstname">Firstname</option>
                    <option value="lastname">Lastname</option>
                    <option value="email">Email Address</option>
                    <option value="gender">Gender</option>
                    <option value="dob">Date of Birth</option>
                    <option value="group">Group</option>
                    <option value="custom1">Custom 1</option>
                    <option value="custom2">Custom 2</option>
                    <option value="custom3">Custom 3</option>
                    <option value="custom4">Custom 4</option>
                    <option value="custom5">Custom 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control mb15" name="brule[]">
                    <option value="is">is</option>
                    <option value="contains">contains</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="crule[]">
            </div>
        </div>');
        theDiv.appendChild(content);
    }
</script>
```

My website uses Bootstrap and the following jQuery scripts:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/toggles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookies.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        var container = document.querySelector('#bloglist');
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            // options
            columnWidth: '.col-xs-6',
            itemSelector: '.col-xs-6'
        });

    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".date").mask("99/99/9999 @ 99:99");
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried using the following button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="addRule()" value="Add New Rule" /><br />
```

If anyone has any idea why this isn't doing anything, I'd greatly appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multi-line string. Use `\` to escape the newline literal

Use

```
var content = document.createTextNode('<div class="row"> \
</div>');
```

Part of your code:

```
var content = document.createTextNode('<div class="row">
</div>');
```

OR

Use simple string concatenation like

```
var content = document.createTextNode('<div class="row">'
+ '</div>');
```

Comment: Can you tell I don't use Javascript very much? Spot on, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, I really suggest you use the jQuery methodology of adding DOM elements. Here's an example:

```
var rowDiv = $(document.createElement("div")).attr({class:"row"});
$("#rules").append(rowDiv);
```

Anyone familiar with jQuery will be able to read this, and it allows far more control over your DOM construction. It's also less confusing, since you don't have a huge magic string that's insanely hard to read, but instead a more object-oriented approach.